# AutoScale - ScaleOUT in daytime and ScaleIN at night?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling

We have more traffic in the daytime and less traffic at night for our website. I want to enable a minimum of 2 servers to run in the day and only one at night so that we can cut costs by minimizing server run time.

Answer (score 1):

There is the Scheduled actions feature in the Autoscaling group. This feature allows you to set a min, max, and desired capacity based on a schedule: [image]